# Serverless.yml rejecting cloudformation "Ref" functions

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

Here is a snippet from my serverless.yml file:

```
Resources:
  LogGroupInfo:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
    Properties:
      RetentionInDays: 3
  FirehoseInstance:
     Properties:
      DeliveryStreamName: ${opt:stage}-analytics
      DeliveryStreamType: DirectPut
      RedshiftDestinationConfiguration:
        CloudWatchLoggingOptions:
          Enabled: true
          LogGroupName: !Ref LogGroupInfo
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
  unknown tag !<!Ref> in "/Users/code/Project1/serverless.yml" at line 56, column 42:
     ...  LogGroupName: !Ref LogGroupInfo
```

This template works perfectly well as it is when used in cloudformation to create a stack. 
Why is !Ref being rejected by serverless.yml ?

Answer (score 7):

The shortcut syntax of `!Ref` is not yet supported within the serverless framework.

As the bug ticket below suggests, you have to use the object based form for now.

```
        LogGroupName:
          Ref: LogGroupInfo
```

[Failure to Create Resource Using !Ref](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3545)

The feature is currently tracked through that issue:

[Fn::Sub and !Sub](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3184)